# Guaranteed way to force application running continuously (overriding taskkill, task manager etc.)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# security/monitoring application that I need to have running no matter what. However, I can *not* remove privileges or restrict access to parts of the OS (Windows).

I thought of having a protection service running which monitors continuously if an application is running, and starts it back up when the application is killed somehow, while the application monitors the protection service and starts the service if the service is killed. To my knowledge you can't *simultaneously* kill multiple processes at the same time.

Any better idea to guarantee that an application is always running?

Comment: Just make sure you have some sure-kill process signal . . .

Comment: Windows Defender might flag your application as a spyware.

Comment: You'd also need a protection service protection service, in order to make sure the user did not somehow kill the protection service. Then you'd need to write a protection service protection service protection service just in case they killed the protection service protection service. Then of course eventually the machine would run out of memory at which point you would have achieved your goal of making sure the user could not kill your program.

Comment: @1800 INFORMATION: As I wrote in my question I have the application monitor the service back.

Comment: @Alex - I can probably call TerminateProcess on both before your monitoring code even gets a chance to run - mutual monitoring raises the bar a little bit, but doesn't offer sure-fired protection.

Answer (score 10):

The Windows team gets requests like this all the time:

"I want to make a process that can never be killed".

"Well *I* want to make a tool that can kill any process".

One of those two people is going to be disappointed.

"I want to make a window that is always on top of all other windows no matter what"

"I *also* want to make a window that is always on top of all other windows no matter what"

One of those two people is going to be disappointed.

"I want to make a process that does not show up in any list of processes no matter how cleverly the listing program is trying to find me"

"I want to make a program that lists all processes, no matter how cleverly the process is trying to hide".

One of those two people is going to be disappointed.

And so on.

I think you're going to be one of the disappointed people.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee - if the user has enough privilege it can terminate your program or any other monitoring code you have running that will restart your application.

Imagine if this were true - every piece of spyware on the planet would be using it.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your program as a windows service - configure it to run automatically on startup, and to restart automatically if it is terminated unexpectedly. You cannot do any better than this since the user must be allowed to control the computer.

Comment: You can't reconfigure your service to restart without bounds however - if it is killed frequently enough the SCM will stop restarting it.  Or you can skip that and modify the restart actions directly to prevent auto-restart.  When that is done, you can kill the app it is monitoring, remove it from the startup group and uninstall the service.

Comment: If the user is killing the process, wouldn't you let them?